# Uncaught TypeError: "#login".validate is not a function

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I'm trying to use the validation plugin for my login form but I am getting an error saying "#login validate" is not a function. Below I have the HTML code and JS code with the appropriate libraries included.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="recipe.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="loginval.js"></script>
<body>
<header>
    <center>
    <h1> Login Page</h1>
    <center>
  </header>
   <nav>
     <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="index.html">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="foodrecipe.html">Food Recipes</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="add.html">Add Recipe</a>
      </li>
     <li>
       <a href="delete.html">Delete Recipe</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href='login.html'>Login Page</a>
     </li>
     <li>
     <a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <form id="login" align="center">
    <input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" > <br>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Password"  type="text"> <br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Login"> <br>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is my HTML and below is my Jquery code

```
$(function() {
   ("#login").validate({
       rules: {
         username: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 5
         },
         password: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 7
         }
       },

       messages: {
         username:  {
           required: "Enter your username",
           minlength: "Username should be minimum 5 characters long"
         },
         password: {
           required: "Enter your password",
           minlength: "Password should be minimum 7 characters long"
         }
       },
   });
});
```

I had executed the same scenario for my signup form and I had no errors with that. But for some reason, I am having a validation error even though I included the jquery validation library.

Comment: Use `$("#login").validate({ etc...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
   $("#login").validate({
       rules: {
         username: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 5
         },
         password: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 7
         }
       },

       messages: {
         username:  {
           required: "Enter your username",
           minlength: "Username should be minimum 5 characters long"
         },
         password: {
           required: "Enter your password",
           minlength: "Password should be minimum 7 characters long"
         }
       },
   });
});
```

You have missed `$` symbol in front of `("#login")` selector. Hope it helps you...